# jquery click not working

Tags: jquery, onclick, jquery-deferred

```
var sba_dfd = $.Deferred();
/*and so on*/

$("#sbas").click(function(){
    $(this).css('background-color','#ed1c24');
    sba_dfd.resolve();
}); /*and on*/

$(".x").click(function(){
    var promise = $.when(sba_dfd.promise()/*and on*/);
    if(promise.state("resolved")){
        promise.then(function(){
            $("#true").get(0).play();
            $("#thumb").css({'background-color' : 'rgba(237,28,36,.4)'});
            $("#div,#wrapper_overlay").hide();
        });
    } else {
            $("#false").get(0).play();
    }
});
```

I've got a bunch of `deferreds`, that resolve on `clicks`.

The resolution of `deferreds` should be triggered after the click on `.x`, but they trigger automatically. What have I missed here?

Comment: 1)I don't think you posted enough of the function for us to help.  2)Do you really have an element with an `id` of 'div'?

Comment: @shaun5 still better than hiding all divs ;-)

Comment: @jandvorak I guess...but after reading it again, I wonder if there are `id`'s of 'true' and 'false' too...

Comment: No, all `ids` are just a placeholders here

Answer (score 3):

I think you have a syntax error

```
expected ')' after '}' please examine
```

which is common to us... so I suggest always close what you open before writing to its body.

Comment: nope, that is not the problem, I just missed it when copying, the `function` still doesn't work.